# How to replace special character in an array with the next non-special character?

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate an inputted char array to another in order to reverse my string and check if it's a palindrome, but I want to skip over special characters. When my for loop hits a special character, it stops reading the rest of the string.

[image: Output example 1]

[image: Output example 2]

This is what my for loop looks like

```
    for(i=0; i < strlen(original); i++)
    {
        if((original[i] >= 49 && original[i] <= 57) || (original[i] >= 97 && original[i] <= 122))
        {
            cleaned[i] = original[i];
        }
        
        else if(original[i] >= 65 && original[i] <= 90)
        {
            cleaned[i] = original[i] + 32;
        }
        
        else if((original[i] >= 33 && original[i] <= 47) || (original[i] >= 58 && original[i] <= 64) || (original[i] >= 91 && original[i] <= 96) || (original[i] >= 123 && original[i] <= 126))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

"Cleaned" is meant to hold the original string characters with lowercased letters and ignored special characters.

Is there some way I can move to the next non-special character and replace the space of the first special character?

Comment: Tip: `strlen(original)` is possibly called each and every time through the loop. Bad. Use `original[i]` instead of `i < strlen(original)`

Comment: Please use character literals (`'9'`, `'Z'`,  etc.) instead if magic numbers. The magic numbers just hide your intent (and sometimes your mistakes).

Comment: This is wrong: `cleaned[i] = original[i];` The current position in the original array isn't always going to be the same as the current position in the cleaned array.

Comment: What is a "special character"?

Comment: @ikegami so instead of i < strlen(original), I use i < original[i]?

Comment: @Alexander, Not A-Z, a-z, 0-9

Comment: @AerialSong, That is not what I said.

Comment: @ikegami btw, you should use character literals like `original[i] >= 'a'` instead of their numeric equivalents. Makes your code *way* more readable. Perhaps even just make yourself a little `bool isAlphaNumeric(char c)` function to clean up all these predicates

Comment: @Alexander I'm well aware of that. I'm not the OP :)

Comment: Ah yes, mixed that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two indices: one for the array you're reading from and the other for the array you're writing to. If you use the same index for both, you'll end up with unset slots in your output array. Presumably these happen to be 0 in this case, prematurely terminating the output string.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at

```
          0123456
original: a!bb!a␀
cleaned:  abba␀
          01234
```

You want the program to have the same effect as the following:

```
cleaned[0] = original[0];
// Skip      original[1];
cleaned[1] = original[2];
cleaned[2] = original[3];
// Skip      original[4];
cleaned[3] = original[5];
cleaned[4] = 0;
```

As you can see, `cleaned[i] = original[i];` can't possibly be right. The offset in the original string is going to be different from the offset in the cleaned string, so you need to have two indexes or pointers.